# Android, перенос строки в TextInputLayout

Tags: android, xml

Проблема: hint не влезает в EditText. Текущая идея: добавить внутри фразы перенос строки, чтобы часть фразы "этот ответ корректным?" оказалась на второй строке.

До выделения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После выделения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот что попробовал, результата 0:

- Хардкодил "\n" в strings.xml, тэг игнорится.
- Аналогично пробовал 'br'
- Делал перенос строки просто через enter в strings.xml
- Пробовал добавить в строку %s и затем программно ставить `setHint( String.format(string,'\n')). Не работало для TextInputLayout, но работало для EditText: внутри поля всё было ок, но при нажатии на него не всплывала подсказка, потому что у TextInputLayout не было хинта.
- Ставил Listener на EditText и менял содержимое hint - ов. Эффект аналогичный выше
- Html.fromHtml(string1 + "\n" + string2).toString;

Текущая вёрстка:

**Label.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/hint_test"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:hint="@string/manager_hint_question"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_default"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_default">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edit_profession_manager_contacts_invisible"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                            android:lines="4"
                            android:maxLines="4" />

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**Strings.xml**

```
 <string name="manager_hint_question">Почему вы считаете этот ответ корректным?</string>
```

Comment: А может быть сразу разобьёте hint на две строки с помощью MultiLine, например?

Comment: Не понял вашу идею. У меня одно поле, и оно уже MultiLine.

Comment: Я нашёл такой репозиторий, но сам его не проверял. Может поможет.
https://github.com/vamsitallapudi/MultiLineHintTextInputLayout

Comment: а почему не добавить сверху просто текстовое поле?

Comment: вам тяжело реализовать эту идею, потому что она не по гайдлайнам. Именно поэтому придется искать и воротить велосипед

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать "\r\n"
В свойствах Text попробуйте склеить ваши строки следующим образом:

```
С#   Label1.Text = "строка1" + "\r\n" + "строка2"
```

Comment: А зачем вы дали два ответа? Какой из них правильный?

Comment: @0xdb точняк, что-то я тупанул) Второй ответ такой же как и первый по своей сути) А за сарказм вам 6 звезд из 5ти